# Integrate $∫\frac{\sec^2x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^{9/2}} dx$

Tags: integration

> How to integrate $$∫\frac{\sec^2x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^{9/2}} dx$$

In my book it is done like

$$\begin{align}
\sec x+\tan x &=t \\
\sec x−\tan x &= \frac 1t \\
(\sec x \tan x+\sec^2x)dx &=dt \\
\sec x(\sec x+\tan x)dx &=dt \\
\sec xdx &=\frac 1t dt \\
t+\frac 1t &=2\sec x 
\end{align}$$

and then it is substituted in the original expression and integrated.

The substitutions seem pretty unintuitive to me. Please share the approach you would follow :-)!

Comment: The expression they substituted for appears in the denominator, so it's not that unintuitive.

Comment: What makes you think that it is unintuitive?

Comment: letting the denominator to be $t$ is one of typical skills in integration.

Comment: Alright.It's not so unintuitive.I agree @AdityaAgarwal...but its just that I wanted to learn some alternative methods ;-)!Because the people in Math SE always surprise me with some new integration tricks :-)!

Comment: @user276387 well yes now it does seem okay :-)!I've been out of touch with integration for quite some time..maybe that's why.Will i delete it?

Comment: I don't think that you should delete it.